# Return View issue with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have code which reuses the below code.

```
return View("mypage", datatbl);
```

It runs first time ok but when its called more times, it fails.

Ex code snippet as below,

```
public IActionResult Show()
{
    return view("mypage", datatbl);
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return view("mypage", datatbl);   // doesn't work
}

public IActionResult Listshow()
{
    return view("mypage", datatbl);   // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't work` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I get http error 404 page, the problem is it works on my pc but when I publish it on the server it doesn't work.

Comment: 404 means the page is not found,you need to find the correct route on the server.